# SyntaxError: invalid syntax 11, 7, \t\t\tj++\n

Tags: python

I am not so proficient in python. I had this code in a practice coding. Since it is a golf code problem, i thought of trying python as i have some knowledge about it.
This is my program

```
Hack sequence of IndiaHacks-2014 if given as below
Hi = 2014*Hi-1 + 69*Hi-2 for (i>2)
Hi = 1 for (i<=2)

Given n, you need to find nth term of Hack sequence
```

I have used the following code

```
T = input()
for i in range(T):
N = int(input())
if N <= 2:
    print 1
else :
    a = [1,1]
    j=2
    while j < N :
        a.append((2014 * a[j-1]) + (69 * a[j-2]))
        j++
    print a[N-1]
```

But i get the following error

```
SyntaxError:
invalid syntax
11, 7, \t\t\tj++\n
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this code and why am I getting this error?

Comment: Check your whitespace and make sure your indentation is consistent. (and fix the indentation of your code in your question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `j += 1` instead of `j++`. There is no `++` operator in python.

OR in this case simply don't use manually incremented loop variable:

```
T = input()
# I'm not sure about this part of your code:
# (indentation and the expected value of T)
for i in range(T):
N = int(input())
# To solve this problem you don't have to populate an array,
# you always need only the last two items:
prev2, prev1 = 1, 1
# We could omit this "if" check because the range(N-2) expression
# generates nothing when the input parameter is zero or less,
# that is: when N <= 2.
if N > 2:
    # Note: in case of python3 use range(), in case of python2 use xrange()
    for _ in range(N-2):
        new = (2014 * prev1) + (69 * prev2)
        prev2, prev1 = prev1, new
print prev1
```

To solve this problem you don't need an array but even if you needed an array you could run the `j` loop variable from `2` to `N-1` with `for j in range(2,  N):`. Note that in python you could simply use `array[-1]` and `array[-2]` to address the last two items of the array instead of calculating the absolute index (like `array[N-1]`). Python arrays can be indexed with a negative number relative to the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `j++` in python. Use `j += 1`.